# Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `choice_option_set` on serializer `QuestionSerializer`

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, serialization

I got this error when trying to create a new django models into a database

```
AttributeError at /api/problemset/create
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `choice_option_set` on serializer `QuestionSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Question` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Question' object has no attribute 'choice_option_set'.
```

Here's my django models

```
class Problemset(BaseModel):
  class ProblemsetType(models.Choices):
    Exam = 'Exam'
    Assignment = 'Assignment'

  topic = models.CharField(max_length=25)
  classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  start_time = models.DateTimeField()
  end_time = models.DateTimeField()
  created_by = models.ForeignKey(UserAccount, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
  subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
  type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ProblemsetType.choices)

  def __str__(self):
      return str(self.classroom) + " " + str(self.subject)
  

class Question(BaseModel):

    class QuestionType(models.Choices):
        Multiple_Choices = 'Multiple Choices'
        Short_Answer = 'Short Answer'
        Essay = 'Essay'

    question_no = models.IntegerField()
    question_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices=QuestionType.choices, default='Multiple Choices')
    body = models.TextField()
    max_points = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    answer_key = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    problemset = models.ForeignKey(Problemset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.question_no) + " " + str(self.body)
    


class ChoiceOption(BaseModel):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=512)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

and here's my serializer

```
class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ChoiceOption
        fields = ('text',)


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choice_option_set = ChoiceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question_no', 'question_type', 'body',
                  'max_points', 'answer_key', 'choice_option_set')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        choice_option_validated_data = validated_data.pop('choice_option_set')
        question = Question.objects.create(**validated_data)
        choice_option_set_serializer = self.fields['choice_option_set']
        for each in choice_option_validated_data:
            each['question'] = question
        choice_options = choice_option_set_serializer.create(
            choice_option_validated_data)

        return question


class ProblemsetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question_set = QuestionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Problemset
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        question_validated_data = validated_data.pop('question_set')
        problemset = Problemset.objects.create(**validated_data)
        question_set_serializer = self.fields['question_set']
        for each in question_validated_data:
            each['problemset'] = problemset
        questions = question_set_serializer.create(question_validated_data)
        return problemset
```

How do I solve this? I followed the Nested Serialization in Django which is written here
https://medium.com/@raaj.akshar/creating-reverse-related-objects-with-django-rest-framework-b1952ddff1c

Here's the example of my API request

```
{
    "topic": "Trigonometry",
    "start_time": "2020-08-31 09:00:00",
    "end_time": "2020-08-31 11:00:00",
    "type": "Assignment",
    "classroom": 2,
    "created_by": 2,
    "subject": 3,
    "question_set": [
        {
            "question_no": 1,
            "question_type": "Multiple Choices",
            "body": "<h1>Question 1</h1>",
            "max_points": 4,
            "answer_key": "Choice 1-A",
            "choice_option_set": [
                {
                    "text": "Choice 1-A"
                },
                {
                    "text": "Choice 1-B"
                },
                {
                    "text": "Choice 1-C"
                },
                {
                    "text": "Choice 1-D"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default reverse name for related objects would be [`choiceoption_set`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward). But if you need to specify alias, you can use [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) argument:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choice_option_set = ChoiceSerializer(many=True, source='choiceoption_set')
```